# Qt creator - no rule to make target for importing existing CMake project

Tags: c++, qt, unix, makefile, cmake

I am trying to import a project with C++ files that I already built using cmake and makefile. I am trying to import it into QT creator. However, after importing the project and trying to debug it, I get the error "no rule to make target". However, the file it is referring to exists and I never had this problem with that file when using cmake.

The contents of `SetupBoost.cmake`, which is in `ws/Arthur/cmake/Project/CMake/SetupBoost.cmake`, is below

```
macro(IncludeBoost)
set(Boost_FOUND FOUND)
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/third-party/boost)
endmacro(IncludeBoost)

macro(find_boost)
set(Boost_FOUND FOUND)
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/third-party/boost)
set(Boost_components thread date_time regex filesystem system program_options)
endmacro(find_boost)

macro(SetupBoost TargetName)
# message("Setting up boost for target ${TargetName}")
set(Boost_FOUND FOUND)
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/third-party/boost)
# if (NOT DEFINED Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED)
set(Boost_LIBRARIES boost_thread-mt boost_date_time-mt boost_regex-mt boost_filesystem-mt boost_system-mt boost_program_options-mt)
target_link_libraries(${TargetName} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endmacro(SetupBoost)
```

What is going on?

Comment: You can use cmake in Qt creator, as long as you have the imported files as a separate project. Otherwise you have to  convert the cmake project to a qmake project by creating a new qmake `.pro` file. You might want to add details about what is going on and what you archive to do.

Comment: I would rather not create a .pro file since I have so many source and header files. What do you mean have the imported files as a separate project? I imported the project following the steps here http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.8/creator-project-generic.html

Comment: Try `File` -> `Open File or Project` and select your existing `CMakeLists.txt` file. Qt Creator will use cmake to build it. If it is a library, you can use the compiled output in your target project.

Comment: which CMakeLists am I supposed to choose? If I choose the one in Project/Build, I get the same error as in the OP. If I choose the one in Project/src/Project/, then I get the error "CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:165 (SetupBoost):
  Unknown CMake command "SetupBoost"."

Comment: The top level `CMakeLists.txt` in the source directory. The missing `SetupBoost` command is a topic for another question. I'm not a cmake expert.

Comment: by top level, you mean the one in Project/Build, right? So how do I resolve it

Comment: The one in your source directory. There might be more than one `CMakeLists.txt` files if you have cmake sub-projects

Comment: If it helps, SetupBoost.cmake is in ws/Arthur/cmake/Project/CMake/SetupBoost.cmake

The contents for SetupBoost.cmake is in the edited OP